# boolean expression in do while loop/c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a program to write: *write a program where user enters numbers until he enters 'e' or 'E'. All number entered by user sum and write on console.*
So far, I write these, but I don't know how to break the loop when 'e' or 'E' is enter!? So, if anyone can help me with this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int sum=0, number=0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: \n";
        cin >> number;
        sum+=number;

    } while (don't know what to type here);

    cout << "Sum =  " << sum << endl;

}
```

Comment: Look up how `do .. while()` works and then try again

Comment: "don't know what to type here" -- You need to insert a boolean expression that tests if  `some_variable` is equivalent to `'e'` or `'E'`.

Comment: @Michael : This has nothing to do with how `do .. while()` works. @Marko, if you want to detect a letter, first you need to start by reading a letter; presently, you're only reading an `int`.

Comment: @ildjarn and once you've read the letter `e` how will you break the loop? (ps: the question has now been updated to say "I don't know what to type here")

Comment: @Marko your variable is called `number` not `letter`. Meaning number holds the value not letter.

Comment: @Michael Because the task says to enters number and when letter e or E is entered, break loop and sum all number entered so far. I know variable letter has to be char, but how am I supposed to enter letter to break loop, when I need to enter only numbers?

Comment: @Marko changed what is read to char and then when adding it up cast it to integer.

Comment: @Marko That improves your question quite a bit. `'e'` and '`E`' have a numeric value; you can test by casting to the desired type.

Comment: Actually the solution is somewhat more complex than some answers seem to imply: You first have to read each line as a string, then determine whether the letter `e`/ `E` was entered. If so, you can exit the loop using `break` otherwise you can try to convert it to a number and upon success add it to your sum / upon failure just start a new loop iteration.

Comment: @Michael Cast operator would be (int) sum+=number; If I put number in char?

Comment: @Michael : He doesn't know what to type there because all he has is an `int`. Had he the correct data type, I suspect he would know exactly what to type – he chose the `do .. while` to begin with, after all.

Comment: @JamesAdkison that would not work; `operator>>` for `int` will enter an error state on receiving letters

Comment: @M.M Yes, of course you're correct and the input and conversion would have to go the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try this piece of code please.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int sum = 0, number = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: \n";
        if (cin >> number) sum += number;
        else break;
    }
    cin.clear(); //reset the state of cin
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    if (!(ch == 'e' || ch == 'E'))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Sum =  " << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's all ok, except when I start program and enter for example 5 and 5 and then 'e' I get result sum is 15.

Comment: @M.M That works with if, thanks, now it seems that all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should make your program accept string as input, then try to convert that string to integer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    string number;

    while (true){
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> number;
        if (number.length() == 1 && (number.at(0) == 'E' || number.at(0) == 'e')) break;
        const char* data = number.c_str();
        char* end = (char*)data + number.length();
        int value = strtol(data, &end, 10);
        sum += value;
    };
    cout << "Sum =  " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::stoi(number)` would be somewhat simpler than your setup of `strtol`

Comment: When I tried to compile, there is an error in "cin>>number"